# How to trigger a JavaScript event when not in a text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a music blog and I want the space bar to trigger a toggle between play and pause on my music player. I only want it to do this when the user is not typing something in a text field. Obviously, I don't want the music player to toggle when the user is typing something in my search bar or a form of any type.

Right now, I'm using the following code, but it will toggle when the user is in a text field as well:

```
$(document.documentElement).keydown(function(event)
{
    if(event.which === 32)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Some code to perform the start/pause toggle
    }
});
```

Is there a simple solution? And yes, by the way, I do know that event.preventDefault(); will not allow the user to type a space bar while in a text field, but it keeps the page from jumping down when you are not in a text field.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Check if there are any text boxes that are focused

if($("input[type=\"text\"]:focus").length == 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

check what element is raising the event and stop input-y elements from triggering the action:

```
$(document.documentElement).keydown(function(event)
{
    if(event.which === 32 && event.target.value===undefined )
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Some code to perform the start/pause toggle
    }
});
```